# Create a page where the users can upload images as an entry

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, image-upload

I am organizing a Logo design competition. What I want to do is to create a SharePoint page where the users can go and upload the logos that they have created (in image format e.g. jpeg, png, etc). Those logos get submitted over there and then the site owner (i.e. me) can see it from there. I also want the images to not be visible to all the users. Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: It all depends on how you want to do it.  Where do you want to save the picture to?  Do you want a custom webpart, or do you want to just load a picture into the picture library?

Comment: I want to create a custom webpart